# Facebook IOS SDK 3.1.1 with Xcode 4.5.2 error

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, xcode4.5

I am new with Facebook SDK in iOS.
Why I am get this error while build the project...

I Just create a new project with basic step from ios tutorial for Facebook SDK..

- Download Facebook SDK (I use 3.1.1)
- Xcode (I use 4.5.2)
- adding "-lsqlite3.0" in `Other Linker Flags` on `Build Setting`
- adding FacebookSDK.framework
- adding FacebookSDKResources.bundle
- adding FBUserSettingsViewResources.bundle

and I try build, everything ok.. so I continue to write the basic implementation on AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

and

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

When I try to build, error is coming out... This is the log

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceFriends", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook", referenced from:
      +[FBSession renewSystemAuthorization] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceKey", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_ACFacebookPermissionsKey", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBSettings.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceEveryone", referenced from:
      -[FBSession authorizeUsingSystemAccountStore:accountType:permissions:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:] in FacebookSDK(FBSession.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I found this is weird, because I use the same SDK and the same setting with the `Scrumptious` example, And the example is running well.. Meanwhile I got this error...

any Idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got the answer... Facebook IOS SDK 3.1 need more framework to work with.. It **REQUIRE** 'Accounts', 'AdSupport' and 'Social' frameworks which is available on IOS6. Because `Facebook SDK 3.1` is created based on `IOS6`..

Note: You should use the **OPTIONAL** flag for iOS6-specific frameworks if you would like your app to also build for older versions of the operating systems. It looks like this.

[image]

Comment: and libsqlite3.0.dylib also! Thank you, you saved me

Comment: In my case it was **Accounts**