# I386 not exist in social ad support account framework

Tags: xcode, facebook, ios-simulator

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/sushil/Documents/project/IndianFMs /Libraries & Headers'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/sushil/Documents/project/IndianFMs /Social.framework/Social, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/sushil/Documents/project/IndianFMs /Social.framework/Social (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/sushil/Documents/project/IndianFMs /AdSupport.framework/AdSupport, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/sushil/Documents/project/IndianFMs /AdSupport.framework/AdSupport (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/sushil/Documents/project/IndianFMs /Accounts.framework/Accounts, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/sushil/Documents/project/IndianFMs /Accounts.framework/Accounts (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from:
      -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceEveryone", referenced from:
      -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceFriends", referenced from:
      -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceKey", referenced from:
      -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe", referenced from:
      -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
  "_ACFacebookPermissionsKey", referenced from:
      -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBUtility.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBNativeDialogs.o)
  "_SLServiceTypeFacebook", referenced from:
      +[FBNativeDialogs composeViewControllerWithSession:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBNativeDialogs.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i have this error please give me exact solution..............

Comment: @Deepesh xcode version is 4.5.2

Comment: see so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621599/facebook-ios-sdk-3-1-1-with-xcode-4-5-2-error

Comment: @Deepesh yea i am doing same things but error are same i add these framework and do this optional but it is not working adsupport, account, social...

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code it is seeming like you have added few frameworks twice. Please crosscheck.

Also, include `Social,Account,Security,AdSupport and libsqlite3.dylib` frameworks to your project. Clean your code and then build.

Alternatively,if none of above solutions work,you may create a fresh project from scratch at a new location other than your present folder because old project may be messed up with references/cross-references and then try to integrate this FB functionality.