# Reference/Linker errors in Archiving App Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to archive my app in Xcode, and had a bunch of problems. After fixing the major ones, I'm having another couple errors. This one, I'm very much confused. I'm using the NMSSSH library in my app, and it works perfectly fine on iOS devices, as well as the simulator. However, when I try and archive it, I get the error saying:
`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NMSSHSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UserPi.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s`

Any ideas on what the issue could be? These are the #imports of the file it's talking about.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <NMSSH/NMSSH.h>
#import "ConnectionViewController.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there is a mismatch in build architectures:

- Your project is being built for the `armv7s` architecture
- But the NMSSSH library has not been build for `armv7s`

You need to make sure that the library and your project use the same architecture settings, so either 1) remove `armv7s` from your project, or 2) add `armv7s` to the NMSSSH library build. Solution 2 of course only works if you are building NMSSSH yourself from source.

To change the architecture of a project

- In Xcode in the Project navigator (left-hand side of the Xcode window), select your project
- In the Standard editor (middle section of the Xcode window), select your project
- Select the "Build settings" tab
- You should now see a section titled "Architectures", and a build setting labelled "Architectures". The build setting is what you need to change.

To find out more about this issue try to google for "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s" (have you tried that before?). There are also lots of questions on Stack Overflow on this issue, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882125/xcode-4-5-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7s). Good luck.